# Como fazer uma consulta me trazendo o ultimo valor de um id especifico

Tags: c#, sql, mvc

Estou tentando fazer um consulta pelo c# com o MySQL, onde tem duas tabelas:

`Compra` --> Tabela onde pega o `IdProduto` e o Valor do Produto.

`Abastecimento` --> Tabela onde irá o `IdProduto` e o Valor do Produto para registro.

A consulta entre essas tabelas já consegui efetuar, onde ele me trás os valores da tabela `Compra`, mas ele me trás o valor de todos os produtos, oque eu queria que ele fizesse seria com que me trouxesse o valor do produto selecionado, um exemplo seria mais ou menos assim.

```
|------------ Compra --------------|
| Id |  Valor |      Produto       |
|   1|   4,2  | S-500              |
|   2|   3,1  | S-10               |
|   3|   3,4  | S-10               |
|   4|   2,3  | Etanol             |
|   5|   4,7  | Gasolina Aditivada |
```

Quando eu seleciono no formulário de abastecimento o S-10, ele e trás o Id certo e era para me trazer somente o valor dele, porém ele pega todos os valores da tabela `Compra` e me trás o ultimo registrado da tabela inteira, um exemplo de como ele retorna é assim:

```
| Id | Valor | Produto |
|  3 |  4,7  |  S-10   |
```

Sendo que o correto a se retorna, é assim:

```
| Id | Valor | Produto |
|  3 |  3,4  |  S-10   |
```

O meu AbastecimentoControler:

```
public ActionResult Adiciona(AbastecimentoModel viewModel)
    {
        var Produto = ckm.ConsultaValor(viewModel.NomeProdutoId);

        var Valor = Produto.OrderByDescending(c => c.VlrUnit).First();

        viewModel.VlrUnit = Valor.VlrUnit;

        viewModel.TotalGasto = viewModel.VlrUnit * viewModel.Litro; 


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Abastecimento abastecimento = viewModel.CriaAbastecimento();
                dao.Adiciona(abastecimento);
                //return View();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Compra = compraDAO.Lista();
                ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
                ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDAO.Lista();
                return View("Form", viewModel);
            }
```

Minhas query de consulta:

```
public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaProduto(int NomeProdutoId)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Abastecimento>();
    }
    public IList<Compra> ConsultaValor(float VlrUnit)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT c FROM Compra c";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Compra>();
    }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar valores pelo dropdownlist](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251248/pegar-valores-pelo-dropdownlist)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Eu havia removido, e tentei fazer essa de modo mais explicado

Comment: ok... Cara tudo está confuso no seu código, estrutura nome das classes, métodos e tabelas. Faça um exercício e tente reproduzir esse cenário na vida real ou no papel, para só depois começar a codificar.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo isto já está no papel, e funciona de um jeito manual, mas não entendo a parte onde está confuso, pois as classes e tabelas estão com nomes do que sera utilizado ou onde é utilizado, se não está claro pra você, me mostre onde está e eu irei explicar ou mudar para melhor entendimento.

Comment: primeiro, uma hora você chama de Compra, outra é Abastecimento. Seu método ConsultaProduto recebe um parâmetro que nunca é utilizado, chamado de NomeProduto porém é um inteiro o que indicaria que deveria ser um ID, trás todos os registros da tabela Abastecimento para a var Produto, que você usa posteriormente para atribuir a var Valor pegando o maior valor da tabela Abastecimento. Isso faz sentido? Nenhum dos seus SELECT possui WHERE

Comment: @GuilermePadovam pera, até me perdi aqui. Você tem um método ConsutlaValor que recebe o parâmetro VlrUnit, que não é utilizado em lugar nenhum e retorna todos os registros da tabela Compra. Você armazena esse resultado na var Produto, e depois na var Valor, você guarda o primeiro registro ordenado decrescente pelo atributo VlrUnit que não está nem representado nas suas tabelas. Por isso está difícil de entender e ajudar.

Comment: Existem duas tabelas @LeandroAngelo, está bem claro onde informei, onde a compra é onde está registrado os valores e o abastecimento ira requirir esses dados, no metodo ConsultaProduto está ali caso precise usar e o nele está claro que é o ID, pois o nome é NomeProdutoId, onde é uma chave estrangeira de Compra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa não é a solução do seu problema, mas a resposta para a sua pergunta.

Considerando que a tabela Compra seja um repositório ou tabela auxiliar (Produto_Valor) onde você guarda os valores registrados para os seus produtos:

Se você quer pegar o último valor inserido para o seu produto, sem mexer em nada na sua estrutura...

```
var Valor = Produto.Where(p => p.Produto == viewModel.NomeProdutoId)
                    .OrderByDescending(c => c.id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

*Substitua p.Produto pelo nome correto do seu atributo

Comment: Obrigado, até posso mexer na estrutura, mas ai que está pois não sei oque fazer aprimora-la, não tenho um grande conhecimento sobre c# ou sobre o nhibernate

Comment: Resolveu o seu ponto?

Comment: Era o que eu precisa, obrigado